# Bacon.js (FRP) - Add/remove values from array and save in storage

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs, frp, bacon.js

I'm new to Bacon.js and FRP concepts. I'm struggling with implementing very basic functionality. I have an array of saved values in some local storage:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I have an asynchronous function that reads these values from storage (returns Promise).

I have `'add'` event to add new item to array and `'remove'` event to remove item from array. Every array update should write down updated array into the local storage.

I ended up with this solution but it doesn't work as expected:

```
const items = Bacon
    .fromPromise(storage.get('items'))
    .mapError(() => [])
    .merge(Bacon.fromEvent(events, 'add').map(l => [l]))
    .merge(Bacon.fromEvent(events, 'remove').map(l => [l]))
    .skipDuplicates()
    .filter(l => l)
    .toProperty();

items.onValue((items) => {
    // everytime rewrites storage with new array (but without old values)
    console.log(items); 
    storage.put('items', items);
 });

return items;
```

So at the start behavior is:

- we read data from storage (that's fine): `['A', 'B', 'C']`
- but when `'add'` event is fired with `D` item, it is not added to existed array, item replaces previous array values: `['D']`

How I can do it with Bacon? I was thinking of `update` method but unfortunately initial value of it should be not a stream or some other async action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Bacon.update`. You can use an empty array as the initial value and provide the async initial value from your storage as one of the input streams for `Bacon.update`. So, try something like

```
const items = Bacon.update([],
  Bacon.fromPromise(storage.get('items')), (_, items) => items,
  Bacon.fromEvent(events, 'add'), (items, newItem) => items.concat(newItem),
  Bacon.fromEvent(events, 'remove'), (items, removedItem) => 
    items.filter((item) => item != removedItem)
)
```

Comment: thanks! I've already figured it out and did exactly in the same manner as in your example :)